# How to get RadToolBarDropDown selected item value in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

How to get the `RadToolbarDropDown` selected item value in code behind file. In my case I have a RadToolBar in which I dynamically create `RadToolBarDropDown`. I set these DropDown Value and Text dynamically as I my code shows.

```
RadToolBarDropDown dd = new RadToolBarDropDown();
if (ds.HasRows())
        {
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                RadToolBarButton rtb = new RadToolBarButton();
                rtb.Text = row["Description"].ToString();
                rtb.Value = row["ProblemStatusID"].ToString();
                rtb.CommandName = "StatusChange";
                rtb.CommandArgument = row["ProblemStatusID"].ToString();
                dd.Buttons.Add(rtb);
            }
        }
        RadToolBarItem item = dd;
        mlmToolBar.Items.Add(item);
```

Now I want to get selected item value in cs when command name "StatusChange" fire. I want to get the clicked value of the dropdown. How I can get the clicked dropdown value?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can handle the button click event of the dropdown items. You can handle it on server side or you can handle it on client side. Lets look at it one by one:

Server Side:

Assume I have a rad tool bar control on my page. Here is the code for the same:

```
    <telerik:RadToolBar runat="server" ID="rtlMyToolBar" 
OnButtonClick="rtlMyToolBar_ButtonClick" ></telerik:RadToolBar>
```

Note that I have handled the OnButtonClick event. We will look at it next.

From code behind I am adding a dropdown control and adding buttons to the drop down. Here is the code for the same:

```
RadToolBarDropDown dd = new RadToolBarDropDown("Drop Down - Handled Server Side");

        RadToolBarButton rtb = new RadToolBarButton();
        rtb.Text = "Bold";
        rtb.Value = "Bold";
        rtb.CommandName = "Bold";
        rtb.CommandArgument = "Bold";
        dd.Buttons.Add(rtb);

        rtb = new RadToolBarButton();
        rtb.Text = "Italic";
        rtb.Value = "Italic";
        rtb.CommandName = "Italic";
        rtb.CommandArgument = "Italic";
        dd.Buttons.Add(rtb);

        rtb = new RadToolBarButton();
        rtb.Text = "Underline";
        rtb.Value = "Underline";
        rtb.CommandName = "Underline";
        rtb.CommandArgument = "Underline";
        dd.Buttons.Add(rtb);

        rtlMyToolBar.Items.Add(dd as RadToolBarItem);
```

Now lets take a look at the event handler:

```
protected void rtlMyToolBar_ButtonClick(object sender, RadToolBarEventArgs e)
    {
        var toolBarButton = e.Item as RadToolBarButton;
        string commandName = toolBarButton.CommandName;
        if (commandName == "YourCommandName")
        {
            //Your logic
        }
    }
```

Client Side:

Now lets take a look at how to listen to drop down button click on the client side. Here is the code snippet for the rad tool bar:

```
    <telerik:RadToolBar runat="server" ID="rtlMyToolBar2"
 OnClientButtonClicked="OnClientButtonClicked"></telerik:RadToolBar>
```

Note that now I am listening to OnClientButtonClicked event. The event handler is a javascript function reference.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script>
            function OnClientButtonClicked(sender, args) {
                $("#status").append("OnClientButtonClicked: " + args.get_item().get_text() + 
                " - Command Name: "  + 
                args.get_item().get_commandName()  + "<br/>");
            }

        </script>
```

All telerik controls have a rich consistent client side and server side API.

Here is the GIST link for the above code: https://gist.github.com/lohithgn/5329716

Here is a example which show cases the client side api in our live demo site: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/toolbar/examples/clientside/clientevents/defaultcs.aspx

Here is the client side API basics help documentation: 
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/toolbar-clientsidetoolbaritem.html

Thanks